# Conditional probability of the life of an integrated circuit

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Measuring the time in number of months, the duration $X$ of an integrated circuit is:
$$X \sim N(15, 9)$$ 
The circuit has been used for $10$ months and still works well: find the conditional probability that will work for at least another 8 months.

**MT TRY:**
$$\frac{P(X \ge 8 | X \ge10)}{P(X \ge 10)} = \frac{\frac{e^{-\frac{\left(x-15 \right)^2}{18}}}{\sqrt{18\pi}}}{\frac{e^{-\frac{\left(x-15 \right)^2}{18}}}{\sqrt{18\pi}}} = 
\frac{\frac{e^{-\frac{\left(18-15\:\right)^2}{18}}}{\sqrt{18\pi }}}{\frac{e^{-\frac{\left(10-15\:\right)^2}{18}}}{\sqrt{18\pi }}} = \color{red}{e^{\frac{8}{9}}}$$
Unfortunately i can't control the result so i don't know if it is right, but i think i did something wrong.

Comment: I believe you have to calculate $\frac{P(X \ge 18 | X \ge10)}{P(X \ge 10)}$, i.e. the circuit works for at least 18 months in total.

Comment: Also you need to use the CDF, not the pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X\geq 18 | X \geq 10) = \frac{P(X \geq 18)}{P(X \geq 10)} = \frac{1-\Phi((18-15)/3)}{1-\Phi((10-15)/3)} = \frac{1-\Phi(1)}{1-\Phi(-5/3)}$$

where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

Mistakes you did:

1. What you are computing is not what is asked in the question.
2. You are estimating $P(X\geq a)$ using pdf while cdf must be used.

A few things to note in my solution,

1. $P(X \geq 18| X \geq 10) = \frac{P(X \geq 18, X \geq 10)}{P(X \geq 10)}$. Here, $P(X \geq 18, X \geq 10) = P(X \geq 18)$ because LHS is the intersection of events.
2. $P(X \geq x) = 1 - P(X < x)$.
3. If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $X = \mu + \sigma Z$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $P(X \leq x) = P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}) = P(Z \leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}) = \Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$.

Comment: Thanks for the additional note